# How do I get a superclass to reference a property in a subclass when the subclass invokes the superclass' method?

Tags: vb.net

The superclass:

```
Public MustInherit Class Product
  Friend _shortName as String = Nothing

  Public ReadOnly Property Name as String
    Get
      return _shortName
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

The Sub class

```
Public Class MyProduct : Inherits Product
  Friend Shadows _shortName as String = "MyProd"
End Class
```

So, in the immediate console when I'm debugging, I do:

```
Dim product as new MyProduct
product.Name ' => Nothing
```

`product.Name` should be `"MyProd"` - but it isn't. How do I set this up correctly, so that the the property defined in the superclass accesses the field defined in the subclass?

Comment: Don't shadow. Remove the declaration in MyProduct and set set the value in the constructor.

Comment: That's not possible, fields cannot be virtual (aka polymorphic).  Use an Overridable property so you can override it in the derived class.

Comment: More info on the differences between Shadowing and Overriding [is available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172785.aspx).  As Hans says and this page confirms, you can't Override a field - the property would be the way to go, though in this instance, I also agree with @the_lotus - setting it in the constructor may be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for the base class to access the shadowed version of the field.  `Shadows` should be avoided unless it is absolutely necessary.  For something like this, you should just change the value of the base field from the derived class.  There is no need to shadow it:

```
Public Class MyProduct : Inherits Product
    Public Sub New() 
        _shortName = "MyProd"
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's worth mentioning that, unless you really need it to be scoped as `Friend`, the `_shortName` field in the base class should be scoped as `Protected`.

Although, in this example, it looks like you probably want *all* derived classes to provide the name.  In that case, there are two ways to accomplish that.  You could require the name as a parameter in the base class' constructor:

```
Public MustInherit Class Product
    Public Sub New(shortName As String)
        _shortName = shortName
    End Sub

    Friend _shortName As String = Nothing

    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _shortName
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class MyProduct : Inherits Product
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("MyProd")
    End Sub
End Class
```

In this case, the `_shortName` doesn't even need to be `Friend` or `Protected`.  It should ideally be scoped as `Private`.

Or, you could simply declare the property as `MustOverride`:

```
Public MustInherit Class Product
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Name As String
End Class

Public Class MyProduct : Inherits Product
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "MyProd"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: that last suggestion worked. I'm kind of disappointed there isn't a less verbose way to do this. But thanks for explaining the options!

Comment: In your 2nd example, couldn't `_shortName` be made `Private`?